# What is INCH/(MILLIMETER)?

Tags: datasheet, dimensions

[This datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/1963afe.pdf) (see page 22) has the dimensions of its diagrams in "INCH/(MILLIMETER)".

What does INCH/(MILLIMETER) mean? Is it a unit of length? (I would expect it to be unitless, given length/length is unitless.) If it is a unit of length, what is 1 INCH/(MILLIMETER) in millimeters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the number that comes first is in Inches, and the second one in parenthesis is in millimeter.

So for something that's to be marked as 1 inch, it'd be 1.000/(25.40)

Comment: And for dimensions without the bracketed figure, they only give inches : you have to translate to mm yourself if necessary